# Is there a way to indicate the DateTime object only has Date value?

Tags: c#

In the database, there are some field is TimeStamp and some are Date, which means some accept both Date and Time, some accept Date only.

I am trying to write a helper class that can generate the SQL by iternate through the data object's property, and generate proper SQL by the data type of the property.

So say, Table "SomeDateTimeTable" has TimeStamp field "A_TimeStamp" and Date field "A_Date"
Then my data object has two property, "public DateTime A_TimeStamp" and "public DateTime A_Date".

But because C# only has DateTime... My program can't distinguish is the DateTime property indicate the database field is TimeStamp or Date....

I wonder if there is anyway to acheive it?

I only can think of...either make another class that has DateTime parameter to indicate that's a Date type... Or check if the time is 00:00:00...

But both way seems.... not so smart?

Comment: (Assuming you're using SQL Server) Be sure to distinguish among timestamp, datetime and date. AFAIK, the timestamp data type is opaque: it's generated by the server and is not meant to be read as date data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that this is tied more to the *schema* than to the specific value; i.e. a **column** tends to be all dates vs datetimes, not usually individual cells within a column.

With that working assumption (which might not fit your scenario) I might use metadata, for example (but not limited to):

```
[DateOnly]
public DateTime Foo {get;set;}

...

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property,
    AllowMultiple=false,Inherited=true)]
public class DateOnlyAttribute : Attribute {}
```

Then you can use `Attribute.IsDefined(member, typeof(DateOnlyAttribute))` to see if it is set per-member.

Comment: Thanks, it great, this is what I want to do.  And I learn something now, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can either make your own type (which should be immutable) or use an attribute.